# SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer on android app

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm developing an app for my company, that needs to post some data on an **https** url.

I'm using retro fit, but I'm getting the following error `SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer`

this is the code I'm using

**Service Generator**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://website.com/api/";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public interface ITrackTraceService {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("beepbeep/postdata")
    Call<String> PostLocation(@Body DataInput input);

}
```

**Call itself**

```
Location location = getLocation();

        TrackTraceService.ITrackTraceService srv = ServiceGenerator.createService(TrackTraceService.ITrackTraceService.class);

        DataInput i = new DataInput();
        i.Eta = new Date();
        i.Reference = "123456789";
        i.Status = "Tracking";
        i.Device = new Device();
        i.Reading = new Reading();
        i.Reading.Time = new Date();
        i.Reading.Location = new DeviceLocation();
        i.Reading.Location.Accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        i.Reading.Location.Altitude = (float) location.getAltitude();
        i.Reading.Location.Latitude = (float) location.getLatitude();
        i.Reading.Location.Longitude = (float) location.getLongitude();
        i.Reading.Location.Speed = (float) location.getSpeed();
        i.Reading.Location.Time = new Date(location.getTime());
        Call<String> call = srv.PostLocation(i);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("Service", "onResponse");
                } else {
                    // error response, no access to resource?
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable throwable) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
                Log.d("Service", call.request().toString());
                Log.e("Service", "onFailure", throwable);
                Log.d("Error", throwable.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

**versions**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/converter-gson-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/okhttp-3.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.8.0.jar')
compile files('libs/retrofit-2.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/logging-interceptor-3.3.1.jar')
building for android API version 23
```

**stacktrace**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:239)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:196)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:171)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:187)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
```

Comment: @Solution, Yea. It needs to be https.

Comment: Instead of https in your BASE_URL , put http. It will work.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @FaisalNaseer I did, but I don't know what caused it. probably a certificate issue at our company

Comment: thanks i solved it by enabling TLS with okHttpClient on below marshmallow.(y)

Comment: In my case .i have used Psiphon( vpn android application ) app on my device so it keeps exception thrown

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue

but in my case, the issue was my `device` was `connected` to the `wifi` but wifi router was `not` having the `internet` connection and then the `exception` was thrown

Answer (score -2):

This error might occur if you are testing your app on a server without a valid certificate.

**The best way would be to have a authorized SSL Certificate.**

If its a testing server then try adding this code in your project and invoke it before you call your webservice.
**PS : This code should be removed before you upload your app to PlayStore. And you should use a server with authorized SSL certificate.**

```
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {

    System.out.println("INSIDE DISABLE SSLC");
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically this code is ignoring any certificate(valid/invalid) received from the server.

Alternatively check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12705373/5251407)

Another answer i have read(some time back) states that changing the version of okhttp(IDK if this is your case, but the guy used retrofit too) to an older one might prevent this error.

Comment: I tried adding the `disableSSLCertificateChecking` to my service generator, and called the funciton upon launching the main actrivity, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Also if I have the certificate, what would be the solution on implementing it?

Comment: You have to consult with your system admin for that. Check the answer link in my answer. Or try changing the version of okhttp to an older version.

Comment: @FaisalNaseer I dont actually remember the version. And i dont have the code right now either. Sorry.